# trying to solve 2 first order differential equations, python

Tags: python, ode

I am trying to solve these 2 equations bellow and I am having no luck, if anyone can point out where i am going wrong that would be great thanks!

```
def f(t,alpha):
    return t*t/(2*alpha) * (1-sqrt(1-4*alpha))

def f_1 (t,x,params):
    alpha=params[0]
    return [X[1],-((3/f(t,alpha)*X[0]))]

T=ode_solver()
T.y_0=[1,0]
T.function=f_1
T.scale_abs=[1e-4,1e-4,1e,-5]
T.error_rel=1e-4
T.ode_solve(t_span[0,1000],params=[0.001],num_points=1000)
T.plot_solution(i=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using scipy. 
Look this example:

```
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from pylab import * # for plotting commands

def deriv(y,t, alpha): # return derivatives of the array y #edit: put an extra arg
    #use the arg whatever you want
    a = -2.0
    b = -0.1
    return array([ y[1], a*y[0]+b*y[1] ])

time = linspace(0.0,10.0,1000)
yinit = array([0.0005,0.2]) # initial values
alpha = 123 #declare the extra(s) agrg
y = odeint(deriv,yinit,time,args=(alpha, )) #pass the extras args as tuple
figure()

plot(time,y[:,0]) # y[:,0] is the first column of y
xlabel('t')
ylabel('y')
show()
```

Result:
[image]

Font: http://bulldog2.redlands.edu/facultyfolder/deweerd/tutorials/Tutorial-ODEs.pdf

An interesting link: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.ode.html

Comment: thank you for you fast reply, would that still work for integrating a function that has another function in it already? so in my case i am trying to solve f_1, but inside f_1 i have another function f. Thanks!

Comment: Yes. This inside function is gonna be just a number.

Comment: If I am trying to add extra parameters, in my case alpha, how would i go about putting this into the odeint line of code? thanks @JoãoPauloOliveiraFernandes

Comment: An alternative form is call alpha inside the function as global variable. 
`gloabal params`
`alpha = params[0]`

Comment: ok thank you, my y is a sequence and not a float, will this still work? im having some errors using odeint

Comment: sry, didn't understand. your initial values? or your extras arguments?

Comment: my values for y, apparently i am getting an error in y[1] because it is not a float, thanks

Comment: hmm that looks like what i'm after, however i get this after the y = odeint....... line. "matplotlib.figure.Figure object at 0xb3fd248c>" have you seen this before?

Comment: thats just the plot library printing the type of the object plot. not an error. make sure you are showing the plot.

Comment: ok thanks, under the plot im getting 'ValueError: x and y must have the same first dimension'

Comment: thank you for your help so far though, im getting values now jsut cant seem to plot them

Comment: Make sure you are using just the first column of y to plot

Comment: nothing :) just dont forget to check as answer hahahaha

Comment: haha, out of interest, could this method be used on a series of 4, 1st order differntial equations?

Comment: you mean plot 4 different results?

Comment: i mean, say if i wanted to solve a set of 2nd order ode's rather than 2 1st orders. so writing the 2nd orders ode's out as a system of 4 1st order ode's, is this possible using odeint? i'd would be adding further initial conditions. thanks

Comment: the problem is the 2 2nd order odes are coupled so have to be solved at the same time

Comment: since I still havent seen this at college, I would have to think a little bit more...

Comment: actually this site says it solves a system... http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html