# solving a system of first order ODE's in python

Tags: python, scipy, ode

I am trying to solve a system of two first order ODE's where all values except `CA` and `T` (i.e. `q`, `CAi`, `V`, `k`, `w`, `p`, `H`, `U`) are constants and `CA` and `T` are a function of time. The equations are as follows:

```
dCA/dt = q*(CAi - CA)/V - k*CA 

dT/dt = w*(Ti - T)/(V*p) + H*k*CA/(V*p*C) + U*(Tc - T)/(V*p*C)
```

Any ideas for solvers in python? I looked at using scipy but all examples I found were pretty in depth and complicated and for systems of second order ODE's.

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27270547/trying-to-solve-2-first-order-differential-equations-python ?

Comment: Please explain your problems with [`scipy.integrate.ode`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.ode.html)

Comment: Take a look at the example in the docstring for `scipy.integrate.odeint`: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html  The first step in that example is to convert the single second order ODE to a system of two first order ODEs.  You can ignore that step, and follow the example from where it says "By defining [...], we obtain the system:"